# Calculate Average between two dates of different rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below table

```
BIDID AppID AppStatus   Time
23390   16  In Review   2017-07-03 
23390   16  Approved    2017-09-03 
23390   16  In Review   2017-10-11 
23390   16  Approved    2017-12-11 
23390   16  Approved    2017-14-11
```

I want to calculate the time difference according to the following logic

First find the In Review status and then get the next approved status and then calculate the time difference. Then get the next In Review status and then next Approved and calculate the time difference. Then get an average.

So in this case what I am looking for is

Say

```
2017-07-03  - 2017-09-03  - 2 days
    2017-10-11  - 2017-12-11   -2 days
```

Last Approved is ignored because there was no matching In review before it

```
Then get total average (2 + 2) / 2 = 2
```

Can someone please tell me how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH ct AS
(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN AppStatus = 'Approved'
              AND LAG(AppStatus) 
                  OVER (PARTITION BY BIDID, AppID ORDER BY [Time]) = 'In Review'
         THEN 
             DATEDIFF (day, LAG([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY BIDID, AppId 
                                             ORDER BY [Time]), [Time])
         ELSE
             0
    END days
FROM
    t
)
SELECT
    SUM(days) / COUNT(*) Average
FROM
    ct
WHERE
    days <> 0;
```

The CTE part calculates DATEDIFF with the previous row, every time it finds an 'Approved' AppStatus after an 'In review'AppStatus.

> ```
> BIDID | AppID | AppStatus | Time                | days
> ----: | ----: | :-------- | :------------------ | ---:
> 23390 |    16 | In Review | 07/03/2017 00:00:00 |    0
> 23390 |    16 | Approved  | 09/03/2017 00:00:00 |    2
> 23390 |    16 | In Review | 10/11/2017 00:00:00 |    0
> 23390 |    16 | Approved  | 12/11/2017 00:00:00 |    2
> 23390 |    16 | Approved  | 14/11/2017 00:00:00 |    0
> ```

The simply sums the calculated days and divide by the rows that has calculated days.

> ```
> | Average |
> | ------: |
> |       2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=011e746896fc92145f9c9b35e81954cb)*

**UPDATE**

Due you are on 2008 and as per comments you pointed out there is an IDENTITY column, you can simulate LAG/LEAD function using an APPLY join with the next ID.

```
WITH ct AS
(
SELECT
    CASE WHEN t1.AppStatus = 'In Review' AND t2.AppStatus = 'Approved'
         THEN DATEDIFF(day, t1.[Time], t2.[Time])
         ELSE 0
    END as Days
FROM
    t t1
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM t
            WHERE id > t1.id
            ORDER BY id) t2
-- WHERE id < 100
)
SELECT
    SUM(days) / COUNT(*) Average
FROM
    ct
WHERE
    days <> 0;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1d72c9fdf15159894d12facd2ac3e76)*

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I am using SQL Server 2008 though so this won't work for me.

Comment: Is there any IDENTITY column in your table?

Comment: Yeah there is an ID column

Comment: Thank you so much..say I want to limit the data to maybe say id < 100 where shall I add that

Comment: Within the CTE part.

Comment: Last questions..can this be grouped by AppID..so if there is another AppID with the average of 4 then total average becomes 3

Comment: I updated the fiddle and added two more App Id's is it possible to first group by the Bid and then by the AppID and then first average at AppId level and then average it at the BidID level   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0be22e0e925daae4ca35a621616b3ebb

Comment: So basically rather than always looking for In Review and Approved pair it first looks at BidId's then groups AppId's together while calculating average of Individual AppID and then averaging it across the BidID